# Running multiple services in a Docker container

Tags: django, video, ffmpeg, docker

I created a Docker image with Ubuntu 14.04 and compiled FFMPEG to run the streaming of a video asset to a DASH endpoint. On the same image I can run the media analysis script which basically use FFMPEG and other tools to analyse a video asset. Now I want to put a Django app so that assets can be both loaded in the streaming pipeline and run through the media analysis. What would you suggest is the best approach? Have 2 Docker images – one with compiled FFMPEG and the streaming pipeline and another one with django, and then share the code between the two? Or just keep 1 docker image and run both the FFMPEG streaming pipeline and media analysis and Django from there?

I am open to suggestions…

Possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/706736/sharing-code-base-between-docker-containers